# How can I convert an SVG to a mesh?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, file-format, conversion

In Blender, extruding and beveling of SVG imported objects, works very well when they are still bezier objects, but the conversion of a SVG path to a mesh is very ugly, with a lot of unnecessary vertex and edges.

Is there a way to better the conversion?

Alternatively, is there a better way to model a mesh starting from an SVG shape?

[image: Example of mesh conversion]

Comment: That AI plugin doesn't work with 2.69 it seems.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, the conversion its self will be scan-filled (like the image you show), however you can cleanup the mesh after.

- For more even distribution: Select the faces that have ugly tessellation. Select the menu item `Mesh -> Faces -> Beautify Fill`.
- To remove redundant edges (and get an ngon), select the face area. Select the menu item `Mesh -> Delete -> Limited Dissolve`. set the angle very low to avoid loosing details of the shape, this will give you an ngon.

Comment: So helpful thank you

Answer (score 10):

You might want to try this addon:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/AI_PDF_SVG

It will do the import, extrusion, and bevel in one step, and will use a better algorithm to fill with quads where possible, triangles when necessary. The addon will also import Adobe Illustrator and PDF vector art.

You can see a picture of what it looks like importing and beveling a file like yours here:

[image]

Comment: That AI plugin doesn't work with 2.69 it seems.

Comment: i visted the link. no plugin to find. maybe needs login.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [remesh modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.62/Remesh_Modifier) to convert it to all of the triangles to quads.

Comment: An interesting trick, but I have more control with ideasman42 answer.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini, yeah. It's not a perfect replacement, but it helps a lot if you don't want triangles.