# What's the easiest format to use to create a mesh object?

Tags: conversion

I think that I have to create a beveled mesh 3D shape out of a stock image. (I am using 2.69 on Linux.)

Say, it's a dollar sign.

I was told to use an SVG curve image and convert it to mesh, and then extrude it, etc.

I've followed a bunch of tutorials and instructions here on how to do that, but it's not working as for example this explains:
[How can I convert an SVG to a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136/svg-to-mesh-conversion)

After conversion, the mesh is still a mess off planes, edges - in plane and diagonal - and so many vetices that i don't know how to even select them to fill or do a limited dissolve that people suggest here. Extruding it makes it even more unmanageable.

So, i wonder if there is actually a different format with which i should start?

Or should i just somehow create the object myself, rather than deal with converting some other format?

Or should i not even use Blender, but something else?

I am so new to using Blender, that i don't even know what questions i should be asking or how - even after several days googling this, watching tutorials, and reading what i think is applicable in the manual. The explanations just create more questions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try to reduce curve resolution first and see how it change the conversion of the mesh.

Comment: Depending on what you need, but using curves you can use the extrusion in curve properties, or add a solidify modifier to it. If you need a real mesh, you'd better model it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a dollar sign there are quite a few options.

1.- create a text object, modify it on edit mode to be a dollar sign using the font of your choice. You can then extrude and bevel.

[image]

[image]

2.- Import a SVG vectorial object and set some extrusion
 and bevel to it.

[image]

3.- Using your image as background you can trace the shape manually as a curve object.

[image]

Comment: I think you just set the record for gif to text ratio. 4 gifs, 4 lines of text.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is very helpful! I think i can make some progress now.