# How do i cut a black and white 2D image into a blender 3d object?

Tags: modeling, image

I want to cut this image [image: Fleur de lis]

Into a 3D blender object, how do i do this?

Comment: I think you are asking about tehnique used in this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTfjrwYcY3g (if I understood correctly "cut"). You should create any mesh, drop all vertices and use `Extrude` tool by clicking LMB while holding `Ctrl` (you may also use curves in similar way). Then you should fill the faces between created edges (or  extrude faces instead).

Comment: convert it to a curve ( SVG from another tool)   then it would be easier

Comment: read this http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1610/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17952/outlining-in-blender/17954#17954

Comment: Also read parts 2 and 3 fo this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27147/1853