# How do I use the AI PDF SVG addon?

Tags: add-on, import, svg

After reading howardt's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-can-i-convert-an-svg-to-a-mesh) about cleaning meshes created from imported .svg curves, I installed [the addon AI PDF SVG](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/AI_PDF_SVG).

But when I import a .svg file, I do not see the options described in "Usage".

[image]

How do I use the addon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are simply not using the good import menu entry.

There is another SVG import tool installed as standard addon in Blender.

[image]

Only the second one (on bottom above and which is corresponding to your [link](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/AI_PDF_SVG)) has import options.

Alternatively, it is also possible that the wrong addon has been activated:

[image]