# Construct objects from SVG silhouettes

Tags: scripting, modifiers, extrude, svg

If I have multiple SVG files forming (the outline of) the silhouette of an object from varying different angles, is there a simple way to combine these to create the object (to the limit of the information present in the silhouettes)? I assume it could be done manually by creating extrusions of each to some arbitrary depth, and then manually aligning and boolean-intersecting them, but that's fiddly (especially if the silhouettes aren't from axially-aligned perspectives).

To be clear - I am not interested in single-silhouette extrusion. I want to be able to take multiple silhouettes from varying angles and produce a single model with a minimum of manual work beyond specifying the angles.

Comment: To do boolean operations you need to convert the curves to meshes (Alt+ C). Note that the topology is going to be a mess  both from converting to mesh and from using booleans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an SVG to a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-can-i-convert-an-svg-to-a-mesh)

Comment: Booleans would be your best bet in Blender indeed, and it would still be a very poor choice with quite underwhelming results. I think there may be software specifically dedicated for this kind of work, like those used for those rotating 3D scanners some times used in archaeology.